# How to show animation effects for a button in ccos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a menu screen, in that screen i have 5 buttons ..on the start of the game ,it shows the spash screen and then this menu screen,.it works properly,but i need to show some animations in this page,i have to show the backgound image first,after 1 or 2 seconds these 5 buttons have to pops out from sides of the screen fom bttom,top and left,right portions.How to do this.

Thanks in advane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it rather easy with actions. In `onEnter` method of your menu scene/layer run needed action on every button. You should set initial positions to your buttons not inside screen, then just run, for example, CCMoveTo action to place them correctly.

```
// after init button somewhere
[_button setPosition: initialPosition];

- (void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    id moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.f position:newPosition];
    [_button runAction: moveAction];
}
```